# Spring Boot - http session replication

Tags: spring-boot, session

What is the best way to achieve http sessions replication for springboot applications?
For example:

6x nodes with Spring Boot app, 1x node with HaProxy LB. 5000 users for my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redis to store the HTTP session. Take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html/httpsession.html

Comment: What about Redis sizing for 5.000 users?

Comment: @Gatp it really depends on the size of the data you intend on storing in the session.